# How do you set a HTML data- tag for a ReactJS TextField in a form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, automation, material-ui

I've got some automation that is looking for a HTML data- tag (example: "data-foobar"), and I have a login.js so that:

```
<div className={styles.whiteBoard}>
    <main className={styles.content}>
        <div>
           <div className={styles.spacer}></div>
                <form onSubmit={e => submit(e)}>
                    <TextField
                        className={styles.input}
                        label="Username"
                        autoFocus
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="normal"
                        value={username}
                        onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
```

where and how would one place a HTML data- tag in the above code?

Comment: you have 6 elements in the code sample - where must it go?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure.   I'm attempting to be able to select the text field so I can enter data into it.

Comment: There is no TextField in react - is this using MaterialUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [inputProps](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) object of the TextField to set the data attributes.

```
<TextField inputProps={{'data-foobar': 'foo bar'}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks Samuel!   That did it.  Using the above, I was able to get a HTML data- tag to appear on the element when using the Chrome Dev Tools.   I still having trouble getting Puppeteer to recognize it, but that's another story.  Thanks again Sam.